# pooled mean and standard deviation

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have data obtained from different patient groups (biosignals from which I want to obtain the power value). I want to have the overall standard deviation and mean for ALL the patients. So I suppose what I am looking for is the pooled versions obtained from the individual standard deviations and means.

This is a lot of data in table format.

I was trying to avoid to develop code for this.

Matlab command grpstats seems quite good but apparently only deal with group standard deviation and mean. I am correct?

ttest2.m seems to deal only with pooled std.

Any help about this?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to read your brain, so please [edit] your question containing your code, which is a [mcve]. You might be interested in reading up on [ask] here.

Comment: "I was trying to avoid to develop code for this.". I have bad news my fried.....

Comment: Yes bad news may be. Our application has currently 23000 lines of code, so would welcome to use native matlab commands for the calculation of the pooled mean and std. Thank you for your warning though